# Executing Nunit from jenkins

Tags: nunit, jenkins

I execute near about 600 test cases from jenkins..But at certain point of time it throws an Error

`Unhandled exception Win32Exception,Error creating window handle.,System.Windows.Forms, at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)`

When I looked for handle count for that process it ws just 700..But what I feel is handle Quota for process is 10000..Than Why it behaves in a weird manner..Please help its Quite Urgent..

Note:I am using NUnit console to run test cases.All the installation on jenkins machine are proper.

Best part is when I run the test cases from console on local problems does not arises..it only occurs while running from jenkins..Is it some weird jenkins Behavior??

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because NUnit is trying to draw something on the screen on the server that it doesn't have permissions to do. This will likely occur if your configuration is such that Jenkins is running under the Local System account.

Verify that your Jenkins service is configured with the 'Allow Service to Interact with Desktop' permission enabled. This can be done by viewing the properties of the Service and selecting the Log On tab. If the 'Local System account' checkbox is set, verify that you've also checked the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' checkbox.

A best-practice for configuration is to create a named user to run the Jenkins service and configure the service to run as that user instead.